# URL Rewriting Add a folder name to URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an apache2 server.

My directory structure is -  (**below is inside - /some-folder/abc**)

```
- app
  - otherfolder
  - pqr.php
  - xyz.php
- js
- css
```

**.htaccess is placed inside /some-folder/abc**

Context root for virtual host is set till - /some-folder/

Now, I want my users to enter this URL - `http://someserver.com/abc/xyz` or `http://someserver.com/abc/pqr`

I want to open the page at - `http://someserver.com/abc/app/xyz.php` or `http://someserver.com/abc/app/pqr.php`

How can I achieve this using URL Rewriting mod_rewrite

This is what I have so far, which is not working -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
#Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /abc

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1\.php [L] # this doesn't work either
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1.php [L] # this doesn't work either
# RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ abc/app/$1.php [L] # this doesn't work either
```

Thank you for your help.

If possible, I would also like to take all query params using forward slash
ex - `http://someserver.com/abc/app/xyz.php/xId/123/uId/938/sdh/8374` instead of `http://someserver.com/abc/app/xyz.php?xId=123?uId=938?sdh=8374`

There is no pattern for query params, they can be anything for an page. Is this possible by a generic mod_rewrite, or do I have to rewrite urls for each page, and each time my developers add a new query param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should work for you from `/abc/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/abc/app/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(?!internal)(.+?)/?$ app/$1.php [L,NC]
```

- `RewriteCond` makes sure that we have a corresponding `.php` file in `/abc/app/` sub-directory.
- `(?!internal)` is negative lookahead assertion to skip `internal` from this rewrite.

Also it appears you're using a relative URL for css/js/images e.g. `src="abc.png"` and your current URL is: `/abc/xyz` then browser resolves this relative URL to `http://example.com/abc/xyz/abc.png` which obviously will cause a `404` since your static files are residing in `/abc/app/` sub-directory.

You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/abc/app/" />
```

so that every relative URL is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Also as a practice to use absolute links instead of relative ones change relative link `<a href="xyz">XYZ</a>`, to this one `<a href="/abc/xyz">XYZ</a>`

Comment: This is working fine for the URL, but is not loading included JS and CSS. I want JS and CSS to work with the absolute path that I provided. Can I mod_rewrite to exclude everything else other then php?

Comment: This rule doesn't affect css/js/images. However you're most likely using relative paths for css/js etc. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/abc/app/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Thanks ! That worked. Can you please let me know the basics behind how it all worked, and why it did not work without <base> tag? Any link/tutorial will be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I ahve some redirects to internal php page, using window.location.href = "internal" via JQuery when a certain condition is satisfied. It is then redirecting to http://localhost/abc/app/internal, instead of http://localhost/abc/internal. How can I solve that.

Comment: Do you have a php file called `app/internal.php` as well? If not then are there more rule in `/abc/.htaccess`?

Comment: Yes I have a php file app/internal.php, which is redirecting non loggedin users out. There no more rules in my htaccess. Just the one you provided. I also noticed that <a href="xyz">XYZ</a> is also redirecting all URLs to http://localhost/abc/app/xyz, Not to http://localhost/abc/xyz

Comment: If there is `app/xyz.php` then it will be rewritten to `http://localhost/abc/app/xyz.php` but you need to understand redirection is different. Redirection means client sees the changed URL in browser and that happens with `R` flag only.

Comment: Thanks. <a href="xyz">XYZ</a>, I changed it to <a href="/abc/xyz">XYZ</a>, and it worked. Please include this in your answer, and I will accept it. everything else worked.